# Setting dependency injection in PHP project

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm trying to wrap my head around the dependency injection concept in PHP. I understand the basic principle where dependency injection is used to "pre-load" all necessary parameters, functions, objects.. whatever is need for an operation to run.

However when I try to implement it on a test MVC I get the feeling I am not doing anything but shifting data around.

I wrote a small example of how I've been doing it. So if anybody would be so kind to tell me what im doing wrong.

PS. I know about the dependency injection container that frameworks usually apply, however there would be no point in using something like that if I am unable to grasp the basics of it.

Example:

```
<?php

class database_test
{
    public function __construct($DB_con_info)
    {
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $DB_con_info['host'] .
                ";dbname=" . $DB_con_info['dbname'] .
                ";charset=" . $DB_con_info['charset'];
            echo 'database connection set -> ';

            $this->dbc = new PDO ($dsn, $DB_con_info['username'], $DB_con_info['password']);
            $this->dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "conn failed msg :  " . $e->fetMessage();
        }
    }
}

class model_interface extends database_test
{
    protected $dbc;

    protected $DB_con_info = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'mvc_db',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4'
    );

    //depende_injection
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct($this->DB_con_info);
        echo 'model_interface set -> ';
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->dbc = null;
    }

    public function add($username, $last_name)
    {
        $sth = $this->dbc->prepare('INSERT INTO test (name, last_name ) VALUES (?,?)');
        $sth->execute([$username, $last_name]);
    }
}

class controller_test
{
    protected function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->view = new view();
        $this->model = $this->loadModel($name);
    }

    protected function loadModel($model)
    {
        //require the php file with the model class (test_model) in it
        require_once 'models/' . $model . '_model.php';
        //$model= test_model;
        $model = $model . '_model';

        //return new object of class test_model
        return new $model();
    }
}

class test_model extends model_interface
{

    private $model_interface_functions;

    //depende_injection
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model_interface_functions = new model_interface;
        echo 'model_interface_functions set ->';
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->model_interface_functions = null;
    }

    public function test2()
    {
        $name = 'name';
        $last_name = 'last_name';
        $this->model_interface_functions->add($name, $last_name);
    }
}

class Test extends controller_test
{
    protected $model;
    protected $view;

    //depende_injection
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'setting depende_injection<br>';
        parent::__construct('test');
        echo 'all dependencies set ->';
    }

    public function test()
    {
        echo 'test controller <br>';
        $this->model->test2();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->model = null;
        $this->view = null;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->view->render('test', 'index');
    }
}
```

Comment: There's quite a lot of code for this simple test. But I think you're making it too complicated. Dependency injection simply means *pass into* what is required. So, if you have, for example, a repository class that needs access to a database, pass in a fully constructed object that fulfills that requirement. A DIC then simplifies all that object-construction. That's really it. There's no need for all classes to extend from each other (you're better of without it anyways). And please, don't call a class `something_interface` if it's not a real interface. ;)

Comment: Isnt that what i did? the model_interface (i know, but it was neccesery to name it something else other then model -> should have been model_lib but it is what it is now) need a db connection so the constructor makes it.the test controller needs a test_model object (the functions within it at least) so the constructor makes it and so on. i know its all over the place, however , does the basic principle stand. if it does, the next step would be to make the class that handels that for all dependecies. but no point of doing that if i missed the basic concept. PS. thank you for the input :)

Comment: I don't think it's what you're doing. For example `model_interface` extends `database_test` and requires the connection info to be passed in. Internally you then call the parent constructor with that information. Instead, don't extend from `database_test` but rather require an object of that type to be passed into `model_interface`. E.g.: `class model_interface { public function __construct(database_test $dbc) { $this->dbc = $dbc; } }` That's what I meant by *don't extend everything*.

Comment: ok. i do understand that. however. tha path goes (as i see it). bootstrap(what controller and method to call)->that_controllers(creat object to render view and load model)->model_lib->database. wouldnt doing it like yo did require me to pass in the db connection? and wouldnt that in return require me to construct the db conn beforehand? ive been led to belive that only the model_lib should talk to the database class? i understan if im asking too much, if you dont feel like explaining point me to some material and ill research it myself

Comment: I think long discussions here should be avoided, and it could be that these comments will sooner or later be deleted, but for now: Yes you're right in saying that you actually need to construct everything beforehand (or at least on demand, but outside the *consumer*). This then obviously becomes quite laborious, hence why people use DI containers. But to make it short, read [this](http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html), and also don't mix MVC with DI, both are independent concepts.

Comment: Thank You very much for the effort. i will look into it :)

Comment: Just watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHBrDWIKW8Q